# Bitmask for obtaining the value in between X and Y bits

Tags: c

I have a char pointer which points to 16 bytes of an array (Therefore 128 bits).
These bits contain some valuable information for my task and I need to parse the values from their fixed locations. For example, there is a time information in between 23rd bit and 12nd bit. I know that I need to have bitmask to retrieve such data but I couldn't manage it.

Could anyone tell me how I can get this information?

Finally, I need to convert those retrieved bits to integer but this is already the easy part of the task.

Comment: how about`arr[1] && 0xF0` and  `arr[2] && 0xFE` and them combining them?

Comment: C#? Qt? Please no tag spamming

Comment: Why do you think that it is a spam? The topic can be answered by people from all those areas.

Comment: Sourav,
do you mean getting the bits one by one? I was thinking of having a single mask to get a part of the bitarray?

Comment: @Dundar yeah, like that only. However, please read the `&&` s as `&` and `0xFE` as `0xEF`

Comment: When you say 23rd and 12th, are you counting from MSB to LSB, or the other way around? And do you start counting from 0 or 1? This is important to answer the question. Usually we count from LSB to MSB starting with 0.

Comment: Actually I have 127 bits starting from 0. So 128 bits in total. The bits are arranged as 128.....0. so, the first bit is the LSB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach would be to select the byte inside the square brackets, then mask off the bits you care about using the single &, and then right shift the byte by the number of bits it is from the lsb, then you have the integer value.

e.g.

`int i = (int)((a[1] & 0x6) >> 1);`

This will get the value of 2nd and 3rd least significant bits of the second word and put the value in an integer.

More specifically for your question:
23rd bit and 12nd bit

`int i = (int)((a[1] & 0xF0) >> 4) || (((int)(a[2])) << 8);`

Another approach in C/C++ would to define a packed struct with bitfields.

Comment: Shouldn't it be & 0x0F? because F0 means 1111 0000 and I should retrieve 0000 1111 which is 0x0F?

Comment: `int i = ((int)a[1]<<29) >> 1;` is actually faster

Comment: you can't cast it to an int because you don't know the endianness